# Where is the SQL Server Compact "repair utility?"

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have used C# `System.Data.SqlServerCe` version 3.5.1.0 to create a `.SDF` database file. On opening the connection after creation, I sometimes receive the following error:

> The database file may be corrupted. Run the repair utility to check
>   the database file. [ Database name = \?\C:\SomeDatabase.sdf ]

Where is the "repair utility?" How do we use it?

I have searched Google and StackOverflow for answers:

- SQL Server Compact repair utility
- SDF repair utility

This [MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172420.aspx) talks about doing it programmatically. Is there a command line method?

Answer (score 10):

Here is a small C#.NET Console App that works:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SqlCeEngine engine = 
             new SqlCeEngine("Data Source = C:\\Users\\SomeUser\\Documents\\SomeDB.sdf");
        if (false == engine.Verify())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Database is corrupted.");
            try
            {
                engine.Repair(null, RepairOption.DeleteCorruptedRows);
            }
            catch(SqlCeException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Find further options in this [MSDN Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172420.aspx). Execute in the command prompt with [ScriptCs](http://scriptcs.net/).

Comment: First try this: engine.Repair(null, RepairOption.RecoverAllPossibleRows); For me this works too.

Answer (score 6):

You can use my sqlcecmd Tool to do this without writing any code. https://github.com/erikej/sqlcecmd

Comment: I up voted this because it is helpful; I will mark it as answer once I successfully download your tool and use the repair utility from the command line.